# Call geth functions through smart contracts

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, remix

Is there any method in which I can call geth functions like `personal.newAccount('abc')` through a smart contract?

If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. A smart contract runs on every node on the Ethereum network. It makes no sense to create a new account on every node.

Smart contracts run in the context of the Ethereum blockchain. That means that they have no knowledge of the outside world, not even on which node they are currently running or how to interact with it. The only way information from outside the context can be sent to a smart contract, is through running a transaction.

What you could do, though, is create a client using web3 which creates a new account whenever a condition is met or a certain event is logged. You would however have to run your own node to do so.